# Building a complicated interconnected request with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a request that should go first. It creates an initial row in DB which is used to connect next rows that I want to save in other tables with the initial (one to many relationship). Therefore I've written a requests that uses `switchMap` to make next requests.

However, now I need to repeat this process with another card which is also connected to the initial and has it's own descendants.

It looks like this

```
Main card // has id
-> card details 1   // uses main card id to connect
-> card details 2   // uses main card id to connect
--> sub card        // uses main card id to connect AND has subCardId
   -> sub details 1 // uses subCardId to connect
```

So I've written this

```
this.myService.send(...).pipe(
  map(resp => resp.id),
  switchMap(cardId => {
    return forkJoin([
      this.myService.sendQueue(...), // returns a "concat"
      this.myService.send(...).pipe( // here I try to save my subCard
        map(subResp => subResp.id)
        switchMap(subId => {         // and save subOptions to this
          return this.myService.sendQeue(...)
        })
      )
    ]);
  }
).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))
```

So, I can see in Network that this does send requests:

1) save main card

2) save options of card

3) save sub card

However there is no requests from inner `switchMap`

---

**Update #1**

It turned out that even though `sendQueue` returns concat observable (which usually subscribes to all observables one by one) it makes only one call to an API instead of making call for each passed element. Meanwhile, if I make the same operation without that complicated logic everything works as expected (presuming the same set of arguments in both cases).

Just in case this would help

```
public sendQueue(list: any[]) {
    const observables = list.map(({request, transferData}) => this.send(request, transferData));

    return concat(...observables);
}
```

---

**Update #2**

I've changed `forkJoin` onto `concat` what solved the problem with that not every request was run. However, I would like to run these in parallel since they are independent.

Comment: Did you miss a comma `(,)` before inner `switchMap` or its just a typo in question?

Comment: try `mergeMap()`: https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b

Comment: @AmitChigadani typo.

Comment: @nircraft how am I supposed to use this? SwitchMap works as expected since it emits a value only once. Also, I've found out that first sequence which returns concat observable subscribes to only one value instead of all (as it does when working with just `concat`)

Comment: Are you sure that every concatenated Observable in `sendQueue` completes? If the Observables in `concat` don't complete, `concat` will only ever subscribe to the first Observable.

Comment: @Sergey it might be a typo, though `forkJoin` accepts a list of args, instead of an array. E.g. `forkJoin(a,b,c)` instead of `forkJoin([a,b,c])`

Comment: @Kos PhpStorm doesn't consider it as an error. Moreover, I've tried both cases. The same result

Comment: @fridoo yes I am.

Comment: @Sergey you're right it accepts both, my bad, sorry.
I've tried your code and it worked: https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/f0c8048d10c0fe42f1e52220ba73eae5
Maybe, you could provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: @Kos for that example I would have to recreate a half of my app :)